# How to pass multiple param in API using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created an API to get response for particular Mac. Below the api I am using and it is working for one Mac request.

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/get_api/10:55.11.22?parameter=Device.status

Response:
{"Mac_address":"10:55.11.22","Parameter":"Device.description","status":"SUCCESS","responsecode":"200","value":"Online"}
```

Above api I can pass only one Mac address.I need to pass multiple Mac address and get response as below.

```
API should be:

http://localhost:3000/api/v1/get_api/10:55.11.22,10:55:23:28,10:66:90:22?parameter=Device.status

Response
{"Mac_address":"10:55.11.22","Parameter":"Device.description","status":"SUCCESS","responsecode":"200","value":"Online"}

{"Mac_address":"10:55:23:28","Parameter":"Device.description","status":"SUCCESS","responsecode":"200","value":"Online"}

{"Mac_address":"10:66:90:22","Parameter":"Device.description","status":"SUCCESS","responsecode":"200","value":"Offline"}
```

Below the code I am working.

```
module Api
  module V1
    class GetAPIController < ApplicationController
      def show
        value = ''
        mac_add = params[:id]
        parameter=params[:parameter]
        client = ClientApi.new
        versionResponse = client.get_call(device_mac, parameter)
        redis_client = Redis.new
        access_token = redis_client["client:SATToken"]
        if access_token.nil?
          sat_client = SatClient.new
          response = sat_client.get_sat_token
          body = JSON.parse(response.body)
          if response.code == "200"
            access_token = body["access_token"]
            redis_client = Redis.new
            redis_client["client:SATToken"] = access_token
            return access_token
          else
            p "SAT endpoint returned #{response.code}"
            p "#{response.body}"
            raise "Retrieving SAT Token call failed"
          end
        end
        puts "versionResponse.status_code #{versionResponse.code}"
        if versionResponse.code == "200"
          value = JSON.parse(versionResponse.body)["parameters"][0]["value"]
          render json: {Mac_address: device_mac,Parameter:parameter,status: 'SUCCESS',responsecode:versionResponse.code,value:value}, status: :ok
        else
          render json: {Mac_address: device_mac,Parameter:parameter,status: 'FAILED',responsecode:versionResponse.code}, status: :ok

        end

     end
    end
  end


end
```

Routes:

```
 namespace 'api' do
    namespace 'v1' do
      resources :get_api
    end
  end
```

Comment: A [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) has a very specific form. What you have here seems truncated and, in some cases, using the wrong separator.

Comment: If you're using the Rails router, only one `:id` parameter is allowed at a time. For more than one you need to encode it or use POST instead of GET. Accepting a JSON array via POST is super easy in Rails.

Comment: I have update routes.Below routes I am using. namespace 'api' do
    namespace 'v1' do
      resources :get_api
    end
  end

Comment: Remember that any values with `.` in them are problematic as that's the separator for `:format`, like `5.xml`. I would strongly advise encoding your MAC addresses using a URL-friendly character like `-` as a separator.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/api/v1/get_api/10:55.11.22-10:55:23:28-10:66:90:22?parameter=Device.status

Comment: Is this way I need itreate?

Comment: Since this is an API, consider accepting input as a JSON POST.